# node.js error ECONNREFUSED on localhost url only

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a node app, hosted on heroku, where I'm trying to hit an API that returns some JSON. That API I'm calling lives with the same app that I'm calling it from (e.g. The node app hosts my web app and has an API that generates JSON from my db).

I'm using the request npm module to make my API call. When deployed to heroku, when I use localhost:8080 as the url in the function I get the error below, but when I use the actual url where my app is hosted on heroku, it works fine. I have dev/staging/prod environments so I don't want to hard code the url.

Thing is, it works fine locally on my machine, so I'm not sure what the issue is - I'm assuming it has something to do with heroku since that's the only difference, but I'm not very familiar with this type of error.

Also - if it helps, I can hit both urls in the browser fine, locally, and on the heroku app.

```
request('http://localhost:8080/api/pictures', function (error, response, body) {
  // this throws error: "connect ECONNREFUSED"
});

request('http://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/pictures', function (error, response, body) {
   // this works
});
```

Comment: In those two requests, one is going to port `80`, the other is going to port `8080`.

Comment: In your post, you say "When I use localhost as the url I get the error below, but when I use the actual url, it works".  But your comments say localhost gets "connection refused", and myapp.herokuapp.com works fine.  Q: Which is it?  Q: What happens when you try the same two URLs from a browser?

Comment: Hey @FoggyDay - I tried to clarify my question with some edits. When deployed to heroku, if I have the request using localhost:8080/api/pictures it does not work, but when I use http://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/pictures it does work. On my local machine both work. Re: the urls in the browser, both urls work on the heroku app and on my local machine.

Comment: @jfriend00 - any additional direction you might have on the port differences? I'm primarily a front-end guy so the server/port stuff stretches me a bit. Are you leading to something like myapp.herokuapp.com is on port 80, but my app is running on 8080, so that's why it works when I hit 80, but not 8080? And if so, any recommendations how to work around this with a localhost port.

Comment: Is everything running in one dyno? In my case, I had split up the application in two dyno's (because I was using Node and Python). It worked when I put it [back in one dyno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979836/make-http-call-from-node-to-python-in-heroku-dyno).

Answer (score 2):

`connect ECONNREFUSED`: the two things you want to look at first:

- Is the service you're trying to connect to enabled and started?
- Is there are firewall between the client and the service host/service port?

In your case:

1) I assume you've started Heroku locally (on a Windows PC?)

2) I also assume it's running on port 8080 (per your notes)

3) Please check your local firewall software, to make sure Heroku and/or port 8080 are enabled. Do you have any antivirus programs (which might introduce their own firewalls)?

4) Also, please look at these links:

- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communicate-through-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7
- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7
- https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/1046
- http://www.debian-administration.org/article/120/Application_level_firewalling

Comment: hey @FoggyDay - I'm on a mac, running locally just off the node/express app. Everything runs fine locally. I'm only running Heroku remotely (e.g. myapp.herokuapp.com) which is where I have the issue. I'm assuming the service is running because I can hit it fine in the browser at both http://localhost:8080/api/pictures. as well as http://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/pictures